# Change alpha of image view by clicking button

Tags: android, animation, alpha

I'm developing an Android project.

In this project i have an ImageView and a button. When the user clicks on the button, I want the ImageView's alpha to change from 1 to 0.5 and then immediately change from 0.5 to 1.

I wrote the following code:

```
public void animate(ImageView imageView)
{
    int animDuration = 50;
    int timeBetween = 2;

    AlphaAnimation animation1 = new AlphaAnimation(1, (float) 0.5);
    animation1.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    animation1.setDuration(animDuration);

    AlphaAnimation animation2 = new AlphaAnimation((float) 0.5, 1);
    animation2.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    animation2.setStartOffset(animDuration + timeBetween);
    animation2.setDuration(animDuration);

    AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(true);
    animation.addAnimation(animation1);
    animation.addAnimation(animation2);
    animation.setRepeatCount(1);

    imageView.setAnimation(animation);
}
```

and I pass my ImageView to this function when the user clicks on it.

But it doesn't work correctly, and nothing changes. What is the problem?

Comment: You have very short time values. maybe it is not detectable by Your eye. Try it with aimDuration 500 and timeBetween 1000 for example.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs: no. i increase the aimDuration to 500 but nothing changed. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`View.setAnimation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAnimation%28android.view.animation.Animation%29) documentation (emphasis mine):

> Sets the next animation to play for this view. **If you want the animation to play immediately, use startAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation) instead.** This method provides allows fine-grained control over the start time and invalidation, but you must make sure that 1) **the animation has a start time set**, and 2) the view's parent (which controls animations on its children) will be invalidated when the animation is supposed to start.

Although you have set a start offset for `animation2`, you did not set a start time for the `AnimationSet` itself, and thus the View has no idea when to start the animation.

If you want the animation to start immediately, use [`startAnimation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#startAnimation%28android.view.animation.Animation%29) instead. If you want the animations to start at a specific time, call `setStartTime()` or `setStartOffset()` on the AnimationSet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this animation code:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toAlpha="0.5"
        android:repeatMode="reverse" 
        android:repeatCount="1"/>
</set>
```

and set this animation in your activity like this:

```
anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.animatealpha); 
image.startAnimation(anim);
```

here animatealpha is name of the xml containing the above mentioned animation.
Hope this will help.